# search function in ecommerce in laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, search, laravel-5

I am creating the search functionality in my laravel 5 ecommerce web application.

I want the user to move the cursor with the `arrow keys` on the search results, but I am failing to achieve this.

Here's the controller:

```
public function searchProduct(Request $request)
{
    $productName = $request->input('name');
    if($productName !== '')
    {
        $products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $productName . '%')->where('display', 'Enabled')->get();

        return view('partials.search', compact('products'));
    }
    return false;
}
```

The search results:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('/store/'.$product->code .'/'.Safeurl::make($product->name)) }}" class="link_scheme_color_main">
            {{ $product->name }}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

And the AJAX:

```
$('.searchProduct').keydown(function(e) {
    var name = $(this).val();
    var inputData = $('.formSearchProduct').serialize();
    var prodList = $('.showProds');
    var countList = prodList.find('ul li').length;
    var prd = prodList.find('ul li');

    if(name.length === 0) {
        prodList.hide();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('/store/product/search') }}',
            type: "POST",
            data: inputData
        })
        .done(function(m) {
            if (m) {
                prodList.show();
                prodList.find('ul.searchedProducts').html(m);
                prodList.find('ul li').first().addClass('activeProduct');
            } else {
                prodList.hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The css:

```
.activeProduct {background: #ccc !important;}
```

I have made this application live. You can check it [here](http://benefitho.com/ankur/store/update-seven). The application is still in the development stage and not in production.

**What I want to achieve is:**

1. When the user searches for the product, he/she can use the `up` and `down` arrow keys to navigate the search results, and on click of any of the results, he/she should go to the product page.
2. When the user searches and removes the search keyword(s), all the products are shown, I don't want that.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have added this code and it seems there is a bug, where I don't know. The bug is that I can only move to the second list item when pressing the down arrow key and at the very next second, it moves back to the first list item.

```
$('.searchProduct').keydown(function(e) {
    var prodList = $('.showProds');
    var countList = prodList.find('ul li').length;
    var prd = prodList.find('ul li');
    var active = prodList.find('ul li.activeProduct');

    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.which === 40) {
        var next = active.removeClass('activeProduct').next('li');
        next = next.length > 0 ? next : $('li:eq(0)');
        next.addClass('activeProduct');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have got it working to a certain extent. I have removed the code of update 1 and added the below code to `done()` method.

```
if (m) {
    prodList.show();
    prodList.find('ul.searchedProducts').html(m);
    prodList.find('ul li').first().addClass('activeProduct');
    if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        prodList.find('ul li').prev().removeClass('activeProduct');
        prodList.find('ul li').next().first().addClass('activeProduct').focus();
    }
} else {
    prodList.hide();
}
```

But this moves only to the second list item on every time the down arrow key is pressed. You can have a look at the link that I provided above.

Kindly help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: try to use jquery autocomplete.

Comment: Any tutorial for using it with laravel 5 ecommerce application ?

Comment: http://www.wowww.nl/2014/02/01/jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-php-mysql/

Comment: @SafoorSafdar I need the tutorial on the laravel side, and not the core PHP side. I appreciate the tutorial link you provided.